# I got "Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061]" while trying to connect to linux computer using requests (python). What's wrong?

Tags: python, flask

I have a Windows client and a Linux server on the same local network. I have simple code on client:

```
import requests
requests.post(url=f"http://192.168.43.227:8080/get_info/", json={"login":"some_login", "password": "some_password"})
```

And here server code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

import threading


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/get_info', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def authorization_func(): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = jsonify(request.json)
        print(data)
        return data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=lambda: app.run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True, use_reloader=False)).start()
```

And when I start client on Windows, it writes "Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061]". What's wrong?

I hope the server would response to client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked your Flask app to bind to the `localhost` address. That means it won't be accessible from anywhere but on the host on which it is running. You need to modify your `app.run` statement to listen on all addresses:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

I've removed your use of `threading.Thread` here because it doesn't make any sense: this is the last line in your code; you're not attempting to perform other operations while the thread is running in the background.